# XSLT 1.0 - Create a Unique, Ordered List

Tags: xml, list, xslt, unique

I'm trying to create a transform where I generate an ordered unique list (where a hyphen separates two values.

I have source

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
    <result>
        <Name>Blue</Name>
        <Author>Hat</Author>
        <TrackNum>5</TrackNum>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Name>Red</Name>
        <Author>Car</Author>
        <TrackNum>2</TrackNum>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Name>Blue</Name>
        <Author>Hat</Author>
        <TrackNum>345</TrackNum>
    </result>
</results>
```

And want the output (ordered by 'Name')

```
:: Blue - Hat
:: Red - Car
```

XLST - This currently returns nothing (I know it's missing the second, hyphenated/concatenated value too)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="Name" match="/results/result/Name/text()" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="/results/results/Name/text()[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('Name',.)[1])]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. You had a type-o in the XPath for your xsl:for-each select: `/results/results` should be `/results/result`. I made a slight adjustment to the key for what it matched against and used.

The following produces a unique list of Name and Author combinations, sorted by `Name` and then `Author`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="Name-Author" match="results/result" use="concat(Name, ' - ', Author)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="/results/result[generate-id()
            = generate-id(key('Name-Author',concat(Name, ' - ', Author))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="Author"/>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' - ', Author)"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads! That's perfect.

Comment: Additionally, for arguments sake, could I add a hyperlink to Author, using the existing concat?

`<xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' - ','<a title="',Author,'" href="http://www.test.com/',Author,'>contact us</a>')"/>` This doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, `concat()` concatenates strings. In this case, you want to create an `a` element. You would want to do something like this: `<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                <a href="http://www.test.com/{Author}"><xsl:value-of select="Author"/></a>`