# XSLT : ordered list with french letters

Tags: xml, xslt

I got inspiration from another thread about how to create an ordered list ([XSLT 1.0 - Create a Unique, Ordered List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328097/xslt-1-0-create-a-unique-ordered-list)) and the answer from @Mads Hansen. I wish to do the same thing but including french accentuated characters. They now appear at the very end of the output document.

This is part of the input :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<div type="paragraphe">
    <w lemma="aprés">aprés</w>
    <w lemma="chevalier">cheualier</w>
    <w lemma="à">a</w>
    <w lemma="ébahir">esbahis</w>
    <w lemma="clore">clos</w>
</div>
```

This is the xslt modified from the other post :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lemma-word" match="//w" use="concat(@lemma, ' - ', .)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//w[generate-id()
            = generate-id(key('lemma-word',concat(@lemma, ' - ', .))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="@lemma"/>
            <xsl:sort select="//w"/>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@lemma, ' - ', .)"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<li>aprés - aprés</li>
<li>chevalier - cheualier</li>
<li>clore - clos</li>
<li>à - a</li>
<li>ébahir - esbahis</li>
```

How can I do so that the list is ordered with french accentued letters : 
a(àa)bcde(éèê)fghi(î)jklmno(ô)pqrstu(ùû)vwxyz

The accentuated letters mustn't come in the end of the output, as they do now, but appear beside the non-accentuated letters (as if they weren't accentuated).

The desired order in the output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<li>à - a</li>
<li>aprés - aprés</li>
<li>chevalier - cheualier</li>
<li>clore - clos</li>
<li>ébahir - esbahis</li>
```

I hope I made myself clear, otherwise don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you for your help or advise. 
/ Micha

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. WRT to your first question, please provide a **reproducible** example of the problem - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also, your input is not well-formed XML (again!).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation of how it works here, I've read the text on the link and modified my code so it's minimal and reproducible and well-formed.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't see your comment until today. I'm using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.2.

Comment: Well, then you should tag your stylesheets as version 2.0. I will delete my answer as it's obviously irrelevant to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:sort select="@lemma" lang="fr"/>` to select a collation (sort order) suitable for French. There's no absolute guarantee that your XSLT processor will do the right thing (or do what you want, which may be different) but with the popular processors there's a fairly good chance.

Comment: The facts are as follows: both Xalan and Saxon 6.5 sort "á"  after "a" and before "b" even without adding `lang="fr"`. OTOH, libxslt ignores the `lang` attribute and sorts them as "a", "b", "á".

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's very helpful and I learn more and more thanks to all of you ! I hope I can help back one day :)